# Unir 2 tablas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo éstas tablas en **sql**.

**Tabla 1**

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   articulo   |   Ubicacion     |   Existencia    |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   cy1112       |   1             |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   ee3091       |   1             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

**Tabla 2**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   articulo   |   Ubicacion     |   Cantidad      | numero conteo    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   cc3111       |   1             |        1         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   ee3091       |   1             |        1         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   EE2102       |   1             |        1         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   DD5131       |   1             |        2         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Tabla 3**

```
-----------------
|   efectivo    |
-----------------
|   2000        |
-----------------
```

El resultado que estoy intentado realizar es éste:

Donde pueda *unir* las dos tablas, es decir, como ven la *tabla 1* tiene 2 artículos y la *tabla 2* tiene 4 artículos, y al mismo tiempo realizar las siguientes operaciones:

**1.-** La diferencia se calcula (*cantidad - existencia donde numero conteo = 1* y (*cantidad2 - existencia donde numero conteo = 2*),
si no tiene cantidad 2 se deja vacío.
**2.-** La diferencia en efectivo se calcula (diferencia * efectivo)

y por último como ésta es una tabla de ejemplo, que se puede hacer un *where* por articulo ya que las tablas tienen muchos mas artículos
éste es solo uno de ejemplo.

**Resultado:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   articulo   |   Ubicacion     |   Existencia    |   Cantidad 1    |  Cantidad2        |  Diferencia       |    Dif efectivo    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   CC3111       |   1             |        1        |                   |      0            |      0             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   EE3091       |   1             |        1        |                   |      0            |      0             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   DD5131       |   0             |        1        |      2            |      2            |      4000          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   EE2102       |   0             |        1        |                   |      1            |      2000          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   cy1112       |   1             |        0        |                   |      0            |      0             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Esta intentado con un `UNION` pero no me da y que debo aplicar formulas y ya se daña.

Comment: sí, más bien a lo que me refiero es a los intentos de código que tengas. No importa que no funcione, eso nos puede darte una idea del cómo ayudarte de una manera más puntual

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo `sql ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes un error en el resultado ya que el campo `EXISTENCIA` para el artículo `cc3111` es 0, y por lo tanto la `DIFERENCIA` y `DIFEFECTIVO` son diferentes.

La SQL que buscas es esta:

```
SELECT *, (Diferencia * 2000) AS DifEfectivo FROM 
(
SELECT *, CASE WHEN NumeroConteo=0 THEN 0
               WHEN NumeroConteo=1 THEN cantidad1-existencia
               WHEN NumeroConteo=2 THEN cantidad2-Existencia
          END AS Diferencia
  FROM
(
SELECT Articulo, Ubicacion, SUM(Existencia) Existencia, 
  SUM(cantidad1) cantidad1 ,cantidad2, 
  SUM(NumeroConteo) AS NumeroConteo
FROM (
  SELECT ARTICULO, ubicacion, Existencia, 0 AS cantidad1, 
    0 AS cantidad2, 0 as NumeroConteo
    from tabla1
  UNION
  SELECT ARTICULO, ubicacion, 0 AS existencia, 
    cantidad AS cantidad1, IIF(NumeroConteo=2,2,0) AS cantidad2,
    NumeroConteo
    from tabla2) AS Tabla
GROUP by Articulo, Ubicacion, cantidad2
  ) AS TABLATEMP1
  ) AS TABLATEMP2
```

Faltaría recuperar el efectiovo de la tabla3, pero eso ya es lo más sencillo.

Personalmente pondría esto dentro de un StoredProcedure y usaría cursores, para mejorar la eficiencia. El artículo para el filtro (where) se lo puedes pasar como parámetro.

El resultado debería ser algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]